# How to handle version changes in an Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, version

When I develop Android apps, I usually handle changes between versions manually (by comparing the current version code with the last saved version code in SharedPreferences.
I searched for a library that can handle that in a more proper way (I use a switch case) but I didn't found anything.

My first question, is there a library to do this?
I found libraries that check if a new version of the app is available on the Google Play but does not handle changes between versions.

In case there isn't, I wrote a draft about one (https://github.com/nawrasg/AppUpdater). The example (https://github.com/nawrasg/AppUpdater/blob/main/app/src/main/java/fr/nawrasg/appupdaterexample/App.kt) shows what I have in mind.
However, several questions come to my mind:

- How to handle success and failure after a version update? A simple boolean return is enough?
- I'm also thinking about adding a callback for success and failure to perform some actions regarding the version (like showing a modal or a toast).
- Usually users update the app version by version (v1 --> v2, v2 --> v3) but some users might skip some (v1 --> v3). How to handle global success? catching each step boolean then verifying that all of them are true?
- How to handle asynchronous calls inside a migration block as a simple return won't work? using handlers? If so, how to handle both sync and async migrations together?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Asking to find a library is off-topic for StackOverflow. The rest of your questions are opinion-based, which are also off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

try this and get your version from google play store

```
public class VersionChecker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String newVersion;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "your package name" + "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get()
                .select("div.hAyfc:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
                .first()
                .ownText();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newVersion;
}
}
```

And than compare your app current version with google app version

```
   val version = VersionChecker()
    val versionName = version.execute().get()
    var currentVersion: String = ""

    //get current version
    try {
        val info = context?.packageManager?.getPackageInfo(activity?.packageName ?: "1.0", 0)
        currentVersion = info?.versionName.toString()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I'm not looking to check if a new version is available (libraries already exist for this purpose) but to handle changes between two versions.